# make a slide down div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make all that gray box sliding down each on their click.
I have 4 div and when one of it is clicked it has to slide down

I'm trying to get its class and try to trigger a click.
it works but only on all that has the same class and only in one that has the class.

```
<style>
#ab4 {
    padding: 4% 10% 10% 15%; 
    .col-md-3 {
        text-align: center;
        img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 15%;
        }
    }
    .box {
        // background-color: red;
        .dados {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            background-color: $copy;
            width: 50%;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 500px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 500px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 500px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 500px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 500px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 500px;
            margin-top: 11%;
            // z-index: -1;
            ul {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                li {
                    color: $preto;

                    &:last-child {
                        margin-top: 7%;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</style>
<section id="ab4" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="box">
              <div class="dados"> 
                 <ul>
                    <li>dfsddffsfs</li>
                    <li>dfsddffsfs</li>
                    <li>dfsddffsfs</li>
                    <li>dfsddffsfs</li>
                    <li class="click0"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <img src="/assets/device.png" alt="">
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
// down device
const downDevice = () => {
    const device = document.querySelector('.dados ul li.click0');

    device.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert('terra');
    })
}

downDevice();
</script>
```

NOTE: just one of 4 div works, and I want each to slides on its click.

Comment: see the site here http://wifi.innovatmedialab.com/about

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with J-query very easily.

The easiest way is the the slide method:

If you want to do it on a click just use a click event in the document. ready section.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".clickme" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
           // Animation complete.
        });
    });
}
```

Here is a link to the full API as there are many useful functions: https://jquery.com/

Comment: hi, I am trying to avoid jquery, only the new and better javascript (es6, etc)

Answer (score 0):

### How the li should go down?

I copy It to code pen (https://codepen.io/omergal/pen/QWLgbbx)

Its console.log every li elenent, what's now?

```js
// down device
const downDevice = () => {
    const devices = document.querySelectorAll('li');

    devices.forEach(device => {
       device.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
        console.log(ev.target)
        })
    })
     
}

downDevice();
```

```css
#ab4 {
    padding: 4% 10% 10% 15%; 
    .col-md-3 {
        text-align: center;
        img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 15%;
        }
    }
    .box {
        // background-color: red;


        .dados {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            background-color: lightblue;
            width: 50%;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 500px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 500px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 500px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 500px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 500px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 500px;
            margin-top: 11%;


            // z-index: -1;
            ul { 
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                li {
                  cursor:pointer;
                    color: green;

                    &:last-child {
                        margin-top: 7%;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="ab4" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="dados"> 
                        <ul>
                            <li>11111111</li>
                            <li>2222222</li>
                            <li>3333333</li>
                            <li>4444444</li>
                            <li class="click0"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <img src="/assets/device.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</section>
```